# ASP MVC Using a DTO from an other project in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to transform a WinForm application to an MVC one.  I just need to replace the client with the new MVC project.  In the old application, they were using different project to separate the various layouts and all data was transferred through DTO's.  Now, in my MVC project, I can access the DTO in the controller and put in in a ViewData but I don't know how to use it in the view, Visual Studio tell me that it does not know the type of the DTO. In the following picture AllDevice are a list of Device.Dto created in the controller.
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuSb0.png)

Here is my controller:

```
private CallServer cs = new CallServer();
    // GET: DeviceManager
    public ActionResult GetAllDevice()
    {
        List<DeviceDto> AllDevice = new List<DeviceDto>();
        AllDevice = cs.GetAllDevice();
        ViewData["AllDevice"] = AllDevice;

        return View();
    }
```

And here is my view:

```
<body>
<h2>GetAllDevice</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nom de la machine
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var device in (DeviceDto)ViewData["AllDevice"])
</table>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather not put it in the `ViewData` but make this Type the "Model" for the View.

1. remove `ViewData["AllDevice"] = AllDevice;` line
2. update `return View();` to `return View(AllDevice);`
3. In the Razor View, you need to define the Model with full namespace, in the first line of your `View.cshtml` file, add: `@model MyFull.Namespace.AllDevice` (of course, make it the correct namespace)
4. You can enumerate through like `@foreach (var device in Model) ...`